# Django REST Framework Token Auth request.user returns empty

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a REST API which inserts an ID inside a favorites many to many model. But when I try to get the `request.user` it returns empty. Im using the TokenAuth method and I send the key inside the Authentication header.

Here you see my Viewset. The `["favorites"]` is send inside the body of the POST request.

```
class FavoriteViewSet(view sets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FavoriteSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]

    def post(self):
        data = request.data
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        profile.favorites.add(data["favorites"])
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

My serializer:

```
class FavoriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

My `Profile` model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField(Receipt)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

My Error:

```
IntegrityError at /v1/favorites/
(1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")
```

Answer (score 0):

The post function should have both self and request as parameters,
so it would look like this:

```
def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        profile.favorites.add(data["favorites"])
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

You can find more information on [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. It still returns the same error: ```"Column 'user_id' cannot be null"```